# Text Categorization datasets for MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dataset

I am looking for a reliable  dataset for Text categorization tasks in MATLAB format.
I want to run some experiments and don't want to spend too much time in preprocessing the text and creating feature vectors. I need something to be ready so I can plug it in my algorithm. I found a MATLAB files for reuters dataset here: [link text](http://www.zjucadcg.cn/dengcai/Data/TextData.html)

Everything is ready in here, but I want to use a subset of this. In this "fea" contains the feature vectors for each document. However, it seems that it is not a normal matrix. I want for example to select the top 1000 documents in this "fea". If you just download it and load it into MATLAB you will see what I mean.
So, If it is possible I need a solution for the above-mentioned dataset or any alternative datasets.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have Matlab on this computer, so `If you just download it and load it into MATLAB you will see what I mean.` isn't very helpful for me (and by extension, for you). Can you describe what happens when you try to select the top 1000 documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is stored as [sparse matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f6-32006.html). Extract the first 1000 documents (rows), and if you have enough space, you can convert it to full dense matrix:

```
load Reuters21578.mat
TF = full( fea(1:1000,:) );
```

Lets check the variables we have:

```
>> whos
  Name             Size                   Bytes  Class     Attributes

  TF            1000x18933            151464000  double              
  fea           8293x18933              4749196  double    sparse    
  gnd           8293x1                    66344  double              
  testIdx       2347x1                    18776  double              
  trainIdx      5946x1                    47568  double
```

so you can see `TF` is now about 150MB.

Other than that, the rest is self-explanatory:

- `fea`: term-frequency matrix, rows are documents, columns are terms
- `gnd`: category of each document, where `numel(unique(gnd)) == 65`
- `trainIdx`/`testIdx`: split of instances (documents) for classification purposes, contains indices of rows, used as: `tr = fea(trainIdx,:); tt = fea(testIdx,:);`